# Работа со строками (перестановки)

Tags: javascript

Напечатать на консоль наибольшее число строк из переданных, которые являются перестановками друг друга. Если ни одна из строк не является перестановкой другой (например, была передана только одна строка или строки содержат уникальные символы), напечатать одну из строк. Если не было передано ни одной строки, ничего не выводить. Вывод всегда сопровождается переводом строки, каждая строка выводится на отдельной строке.
Пример:

node permutations.js ABCDE EDBCA XYZ ZYX ZXY 
XYZ 
ZYX 
ZXY

Answer (score 1):

Сложно понять, что именно надо сделать. Я сделал так, как прочитал.

```js
function printMaxTranspositionStrings(string) {
  if (!string) return;
  var words = string.split(' ');
  if (!words.length) return;
  if (words.length === 1) {
    printString(words[0]);
    return;
  }
  var uniqueWords = words.reduce(function(res, word) {
    var sortedWord = word.split('').sort().join('');
    if (!res.sortedWords[sortedWord]) {
      res.sortedWords[sortedWord] = [];
    }
    res.sortedWords[sortedWord].push(word);
    if (sortedWord.length > res.max.length) {
      res.max = sortedWord;
    }
    return res;
  }, {
    sortedWords: {},
    max: ''
  });
  uniqueWords.sortedWords[uniqueWords.max].forEach(printString);
}

function printString(string) {
  console.log(string);
}

printMaxTranspositionStrings('ABCDE EDBCA XYZ ZYX ZXY XYZ ZYX ZXY');
```